# CSS3 Animation Delay Times after next move

Tags: css

I have a problem that is why css3 animation finish one time . than it will delay next time to go.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/slczH/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last keyframe is not needed: give it a shot with the following:

```
@-webkit-keyframes sport{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform:  rotateY(186deg);
        -webkit-transform:  translate(10px) ;
    }
    50%{
        -webkit-transform:  translate(500px) ;
    }
    51%{
        -webkit-transform:  translate(500px) rotateY(186deg) 
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform:  translate(0px) rotateY(186deg) 
    } 
}
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rtAKk/)**

Comment: buy the way , is there any way to debug css3 animation?

Comment: @user3345792 Feel free to accept the answer if it helped, cheers.

Comment: @user3345792 Well what is it that you want to debug about them

Comment: if you write wrong . it not work or behave weird. if it's js , Browser will tall you where is wrong . but css not , particularly css3 animation wrong ...(⊙o⊙)…